# retorno de casas decimais em consultas do sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

Na consulta abaixo gostaria de retornar somente 3 casas após a vírgula para as colunas: size in mb, availablespaceinmb
Já para coluna available, gostaria de retornar sem nenhuma casa decimal após a vírgula.

Como posso fazer isso.

```
SELECT
rtrim(name)as name,
((size)/128.0) as'size in MB',
((size)/128.0) -CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name,'SpaceUsed')AS int)/128.0 AS AvailableSpaceInMB,
((((size)/128.0) -CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name,'SpaceUsed')AS int)/128.0)/((size)/128.0))
* 100 as'% Available', filename
FROM sysfiles
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você está falando de apresentação do resultado e usa MS SQL Server 2012 ou superior, pode usar a função `FORMAT` para determinar o número de casas depois da vírgula, assim:

```
select format(1234.5678, '#.000')
```

O resultado será `1234.568` (veja que foi arrendondado).

E, para apresentar sem nenhuma casa decimal:

```
select format(1234.5678, '#')
```

O resultado será `1235` (também arrendondado).

**Update:** Em versões anteriores, você pode usar a função `ROUND`:

```
select round(1234.5678, 3)
select round(1234.5678, 0)
```

Resultados: `1234.568` e `1235`.

Ou pode converter o valor para `DECIMAL` limitando o número de casas decimais:

```
select cast(1234.5678 as decimal(10, 3))
select cast(1234.5678 as decimal(10, 0))
```

Resultados: também `1234.568` e `1235`.

No seu comando, basta aplicar o método escolhido sobre cada coluna resultante do comando SELECT. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT
    rtrim(name)as name,
    ROUND(((size)/128.0), 3) as'size in MB',
    ROUND(((size)/128.0) -CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name,'SpaceUsed')AS int)/128.0, 3) 
            AS AvailableSpaceInMB,
    ROUND(((((size)/128.0) 
            -CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name,'SpaceUsed') AS int)/128.0)
            /((size)/128.0)) * 100, 0) as'% Available', 
    filename
FROM 
    sysfiles
```

Comment: Você poderia por favor me dar um exemplo para versões anteriores a 2012?

Consegue também formatar essa consulta que deixei, para que seja apresentada nessas condições?

Obrigado.

Comment: @JeanBraz Atualizei minha resposta com opções para versões anteriores.

Answer (score 1):

Certo,

Existem duas formas:

1° Forma:

Primeiro retornando um numero em varchar:

```
select cast(123789.456 as varchar))
```

Segundo retornando onde esta o ponto para separar o numero de casas decimais.

```
select charindex('.',cast(123789.456 as varchar))
```

Finalmente Retornando o numero da terceira casa decimal, considerando o índice do ponto + a quantidade de números excedentes a terceira casa decimal

```
select SUBSTRING(cast(123789.456 as varchar), charindex('.',cast(123789.456 as varchar))+3,1)
```

2° Forma:
Retornando o numero final de casas decimais de um numero arredondado:
-- Truncado a terceira casa

```
select right(cast(round(123789.45678, 3, 1) as numeric(15,3)),1)
```

-- Arredondando a terceira casa

```
select right(cast(round(123789.45678, 3) as numeric(15,3)),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ola, para trazer os resultados com com separador de decimal eu fiz assim.

```
DECLARE @VALOR  DECIMAL(15,2)
DECLARE @X  INT

SET @VALOR  = 2111113.55
SET @X = CASE   WHEN LEN(@VALOR) BETWEEN 1 AND 6 THEN 3
                WHEN LEN(@VALOR) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN 2
                WHEN LEN(@VALOR) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN 1 
                WHEN LEN(@VALOR) BETWEEN 13 AND 15 THEN 0 END

SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(convert(varchar,cast(@VALOR as money),1),(LEN(@VALOR)-@X)),',','.')  + ',' + RIGHT(@VALOR,2)
```